# How to "runAction" forever with completion block parameter included

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I declared a method in a SpriteKit game I have been working on that runs an action where a SpriteNode moves up and on competition, moves down.

```
func yFluctuation(node: SKSpriteNode) {
  let flucUp = SKAction.moveToY(node.position.y + 9, duration: 2.0)
  let flucDown = SKAction.moveToY(node.position.y - 9, duration: 2.0)
    node.runAction(flucUp, completion: {node.runAction(flucDown)})
}
```

I have tried `SKAction.repeatActionForver()`, however it only works on `flucUp` and gives an error if I include the completion block in it. If anyone has a solution of any kind, even if it means changing the structure of the function, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: an action that repeats forever will never "run to completion", so there's that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a way to test it, but will repeating a sequence forever work? I confess to it being something of a shot in the dark though.

```
SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([flucUp, flucDown]))
```